# Write a program that asks the user for a zip code and prints the bar code. in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

basically each digit from 0-9 is encoded with two full bars and three half bars and I'm supposed to accept a set of 5 numbers from the user and convert each number into their respective bar thing.

I am extremely new at this so this was my best attempt at it. its giving me the error message that the 'get_barcode_part' identifier is not found. so im not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Try putting the `get_barcode_part` *before* the `main` method.

Comment: You also have written a function to extract the digits from zipCode, have you?

Comment: Please extract a minimal example. People are good at guessing what's going on, but you are still required to provide sufficient info. You can and should separate different issues, too, like barcode rendering, which is independent of the undeclared identifier you are struggling with here.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this line before the `main()` function

```
string get_barcode_part(int); //function prototype
```

A function prototype is a declaration of a function that omits the function body. It specifies the function's name, argument types and return type.
As the compiler compiles from top to bottom it should know about the functions you are going to use,that can be achieved by either defining the function before `main()` or by providing a declaration/prototype before the compiler encounters the function call.

```
return_type func_name(type param_name1, type param_name2, …,type param_nameN);
```